# How can one define the trace of a linear operator on any finite dimensional vector space, using the fact that $tr(A) = tr(P^{-1}AP)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Firstly, I had to prove that $tr(AB) = tr(BA)$ and deduce that the trace is an invariant of similarity i.e. that $tr(A) = tr(P^{-1}AP)$ for any $A$ and invertible $P$. I could prove the first part - Now here's my deduction:
Suppose $B$ is similar to $A$ i.e. $B = P^{-1}AP$
Consider $tr(B) = tr(P^{-1}AP) = tr(APP^{-1}) = tr(A)$ 
Would this suffice?
I then have to explain how I can use this fact to define the trace of a linear operator $\phi : V \rightarrow V$ on any finite dimensional vector space $V$. The hint given says to consider the actual definition of determinant. 
I'm not sure where to start - any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: But I proved that $tr(AB) = tr(BA)$ - why can't this be applied?

Comment: @mathlete, whoops I missed the earlier bit, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is correct! Now consider an operator $\phi:V\to V$, chose any basis $(e_i)$, suppose $\phi$ is given by matrix $A$, define $tr(\phi):=tr(A)$. What remains is to show this do not depend on the basis.

Comment: Could you explain in a little more detail why you've done those steps?

Comment: @Mathlete The point is that you are showing that $tr(\phi):=tr(A)$ is a well-defined map. That is, all matrix representations of $\phi$ are going to give you the same trace, so it doesn't matter which one you pick: you always get the same trace.

Comment: Oh right I see. How would I then show that it does not depend on the basis?

Comment: @Mathlete That is exactly what you have proved.

Comment: @Mathlete ...you already showed that! If $A$ is one matrix representing $\phi$, then *all the others are* $\{XAX^{-1}\mid X \text{invertible}\}$. It sounds like you need to spend a little time pondering this before you move on... these are important things to remember :)

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I'm being silly. Can I ask where the definition of the determinant comes into play here?

Comment: @Mathlete I don't see what the determinant has to do with this problem, but that may just because I think this method is already extremely simple, and that makes me lazy. Someone might point out an alternative solution using it soon.

Comment: Yes I think so too, I just want to understand why my lecturer might have thought it would be important to include. Any ideas?

Comment: I understand what you were getting at @rschwieb; if we take a linear map (with the conditions specified above), we can define its trace by choosing a basis for V and describing the operator as a matrix relative to this basis, and taking the trace of this square matrix. As we have shown that all matrices will be similar, it does not matter which basis we take.

Comment: The above comment was aimed at you as well @MaMing, thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mathlete You seem to be taking the Algebra 1B course at Bath. If this is true, I can be fairly confident that the reason the determinant hint was given is that the method of proof is the same - you define $\operatorname{det}(\phi)=\det(A)$ for any matrix $A$ representing $\phi$, and then show that this definition is independent of the choice of $A$. I don't think you'll have seen too many proofs of well-definition in the courses so far, so it seems helpful to remind you of one.